# How to make background Image to fill fullscreen in android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, fullscreen

Everyone! I try to make my splash screen to full fill a whole screen by using code below:

In styles.xml file:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.EBanking" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="ColdFullscreen" parent="Theme.EBanking">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/splash_background</item>
</style>
```

in Manifest.xml file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.themirrorcode.ebanking">
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.EBanking">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/ColdFullscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

activity_layout.xml code:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"/>
```

The app background isn't fullscreen, please see the picture.
Thank you!
[App Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWHCe.png)

**Edit**

Want Image to take Full Screen.Which is mention in above link

Answer (score -1):

Change this line

```
<style name="Theme.EBanking" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
```

to this

```
<style name="Theme.EBanking" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

after that add
`android:background="@drawable/splash_background"` to activity_layout.xml
and remove `android:theme="@style/ColdFullscreen"` from your Manifest.xml file

Comment: add the whole code of your Manifest.xml file and the code of the layout in your app to your question

Comment: I have edited my question as you need. Thank You for your comments.

Comment: i edited my answer, don't forget to change to `NoActionBar` as well

Comment: Have no change, when I hiding ActionBar and TitleBar. please see attached picture in my question above.